# Data binding with provider in Ionic3 and Angular2

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, data-binding, ionic3

In my app, I have a list to display which has a lot of data. The data is getting populated in a provider in a loop from Firebase. Now don't want to wait for the entire data to be loaded.
So how can I bind my page list variable with the provider so that it displays as much as it has fetched?

Following is the code where I am populating a list in my provider class.

```
dataArray = new Array<any>();
for (let item of items) {
      this.afDB.object(`root`+item)
      .subscribe(data=> {
        this.dataArray.push(data);
      });
    }
```

So the dataArray will be populated with time. Now I a importing the provider class in a page where I want to show the list with the data in dataArray.
If I return dataArray then it has to be after the complete data fetching. So Is there a way I can bind the dataArray with some variable in my page or use it directly in the page?

Here in the HTML code:

```
<ion-list>
     <ion-item *ngFor="let item of items">
         {{item.value}}
     </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

items is a variable in the page TS file.

Comment: Can you show the `code`?

Comment: ` for (let list of lists) {
          this.afDB.object(`root`+list)
          .subscribe(data=> {
            this.displayList.push(data);
          });
        }` This generates the displayList which is in the provider class. I want to display in the page.

Comment: You need to show more `code` to get the help here and also put those code on your question area with `formatting`.

Comment: Where is your `html` page code?

Comment: In html its a simple <ion-list> with *ngFor which displays a list data. The question is how to bind this list data with dataArray.

Comment: If you need to know how to bind it directly to the `html` page then you have to show that `code` too on your original question with `formating`.

Comment: If you need to bind the `dataArray` to your `html` then why you used `items` array?

Comment: I have no reason to use it. Could you let me know how can I use dataArray in my HTML page. In the TS page I can use it by importing the provider and using the reference. I don't know how to place it in the HTML page.

Comment: OK, then can you show the `code` of your page's `ts` file too?

Answer (score 0):

Got my mistake.

```
import { DataProvider } from './../../providers/data/data';
constructor(private _data: DataProvider) {
  }
```

Here I was using `Private` for the reference. That is why I was unable to use it in the HTML class. It has to be `Public`.